# Aggregation matched records in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to match records. Need to check how many records contain the  **NAME1** value in MongoDB aggregation.I need without using **unwind**. I am not able to figure out the solution.someone give best solution for this.

```
[
  {
    "userId": "dd",
    "parameter": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "value": 150,
      }
      ,
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "value": 150,
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "value": 150,
      }
      
    
    ]
  }
  
  
  {
    "userId": "dd",
    "parameter": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "value": 150,
      }
      ,
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "value": 150,
      },
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "value": 150,
      }
      
    
    ]
  },
  
]
```

Here **NAME1**  have 2 records and  **name2**  and **name3** have only record some like this output

```
[
{
    "_id" : "name1 contain records",
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : "name2 contain records",
    "count" : 1
},

{
    "_id" : "name3 contain records",
    "count" : 1
}]
```

Comment: Why the requirement to avoid using `$unwind`?

Comment: You can add no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         parameter: {
            $sortArray: {
               input: "$parameter",
               sortBy: { name: 1 }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         parameter: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$parameter",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: [{ $last: "$$value.name" }, "$$this.name"] },
                     then: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                           { $slice: ["$$value", { $subtract: [{ $size: "$$value" }, 1] }] },
                           [{ name: "$$this.name", count: { $add: [{ $last: "$$value.count" }, 1] } }]
                        ]
                     },
                     else: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                           "$$value",
                           [{ name: "$$this.name", count: 1 }]
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

In order to get exactly the out as provided in your question, you must use `$unwind` at the end. Otherwise it is not possible, I think.